# Controlling observable buffering by observable itself

Tags: rx-scala

I'm trying to slice observable stream by itself, eg.:

```
val source = Observable.from(1 to 10).share
val boundaries = source.filter(_ % 3 == 0)
val result = source.tumblingBuffer(boundaries)

result.subscribe((buf) => println(buf.toString))
```

Te output is:

```
Buffer()
Buffer()
Buffer()
Buffer()
```

`source` is probably iterated on `boundaries` line, before it reaches the `result` so it only create boundaries and resulting buffers but there's nothing to fill in.

My approach to this is using `publish`/`connect`:

```
val source2 = Observable.from(1 to 10).publish
val boundaries2 = source2.filter(_ % 3 == 0)
val result2 = source2.tumblingBuffer(boundaries2)

result2.subscribe((buf) => println(buf.toString))
source2.connect
```

This produces output alright:

```
Buffer(1, 2)
Buffer(3, 4, 5)
Buffer(6, 7, 8)
Buffer(9, 10)
```

Now I just need to hide `connect` from outer world and `connect` it when `result` gets subscribed (I am doing this inside a class and I don't want to expose it). Something like:

```
val source3 = Observable.from(1 to 10).publish
val boundaries3 = source3.filter(_ % 3 == 0)
val result3 = source3
          .tumblingBuffer(boundaries3)
          .doOnSubscribe(() => source3.connect)

result3.subscribe((buf) => println(buf.toString))
```

But now, `doOnSubscribe` action gets never called so published `source` gets never connected...

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with your `publish` solution. There is however an alternative `publish` operator that takes a lambda as its argument ([see documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish(rx.functions.Func1))) of type `Observable[T] => Observable[R]`. The argument of this lambda is the original stream, to which you can safely subscribe multiple times. Within the lambda you transform the original stream to your liking; in your case you filter the stream **and** buffer it on that filter.

```
Observable.from(1 to 10)
    .publish(src => src.tumblingBuffer(src.filter(_ % 3 == 0)))
    .subscribe(buf => println(buf.toString()))
```

The best thing of this operator is that you don't need to call anything like `connect` afterwards.